# xcrun usdz_converter issues after Xcode 10.1 update

Tags: xcode, xcrun, usdz

Before updating Xcode today I was able to convert .obj files to usdz without any issue. I have tried searching the internet and even turning it off and back on again. Has anyone else ran across this issue before?

```
$ xcrun usdz_converter ~/Desktop/obj_file/demo.obj ~/Desktop/obj_file/demo.usdz -v -a -l
objc[969]: Class MDLTSUZipReadChannel is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO (0x7fff87025898) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/usdz_converter.dylib (0x1080001d0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[969]: Class MDLTSUZipFileWriter is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO (0x7fff870255c8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/usdz_converter.dylib (0x108000220). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[969]: Class MDLTSULogCatThreadSafeMutableSet is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO (0x7fff87025758) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/usdz_converter.dylib (0x108000270). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[969]: Class MDLTSUContainedZipArchive is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO (0x7fff87025a28) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/usdz_converter.dylib (0x1080002c0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[969]: Class MDLTSULogHelper is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO (0x7fff87025398) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/usdz_converter.dylib (0x108000310). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[969]: Class MDLTSUIOUtils is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO (0x7fff87025640) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/usdz_converter.dylib (0x108000388). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[969]: Class MDLTSUZipWriter is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO (0x7fff87025c08) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/usdz_converter.dylib (0x1080003b0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[969]: Class MDLTSUZipWriterEntry is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO (0x7fff87025c30) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/usdz_converter.dylib (0x1080003d8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[969]: Class MDLTSUBundleLookupClass is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO (0x7fff870257d0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/usdz_converter.dylib (0x1080004c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[969]: Class MDLTSUTemporaryDirectory is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO (0x7fff87025988) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/usdz_converter.dylib (0x1080004f0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[969]: Class MDLTSUFileIOChannel is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO (0x7fff87025438) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/usdz_converter.dylib (0x108000540). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[969]: Class MDLTSUEncodedBlockInfoInternal is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO (0x7fff870257f8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/usdz_converter.dylib (0x108000590). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[969]: Class MDLTSUEncodedBlockInfoWithDecodedLengthInternal is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO (0x7fff87025848) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/usdz_converter.dylib (0x1080005e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[969]: Class MDLTSUReadChannelInputStreamAdapter is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO (0x7fff870253e8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/usdz_converter.dylib (0x108000630). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[969]: Class MDLTSUZipFileArchive is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO (0x7fff870256b8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/usdz_converter.dylib (0x108000680). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[969]: Class MDLTSUZipFileDescriptorWrapper is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO (0x7fff870256e0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/usdz_converter.dylib (0x1080006a8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[969]: Class MDLTSUZipArchive is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO (0x7fff870258e8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/usdz_converter.dylib (0x108000720). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[969]: Class MDLTSUZipEntry is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO (0x7fff87025a00) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/usdz_converter.dylib (0x108000798). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[969]: Class MDLTSUAssertionHandler is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO (0x7fff87025550) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/usdz_converter.dylib (0x108000838). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[969]: Class MDLTSUBufferedReadChannel is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO (0x7fff87025ca8) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/usdz_converter.dylib (0x108000860). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[969]: Class MDLTSUBufferedReadChannelHelper is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO (0x7fff87025cd0) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/usdz_converter.dylib (0x108000888). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[969]: Class MDLTSUZipInflateReadChannel is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/ModelIO.framework/Versions/A/ModelIO (0x7fff87025668) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/usdz_converter.dylib (0x108000900). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

usdz_converter
Version: 1.008

-v: Verbose output
-a: Generate .usda intermediate file
-l: Leave generated .usda file
```

Comment: Is it failing? If it's working properly I would just submit a bug report to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following response from Apple on their developer forums.

> Yes, we're seeing this too.
>   It appears(?) to be harmless, but if you encounter any issues beyond the warnings please let us know (bugreporter.apple.com).